# Django site management is faile

Tags: python, django, templates, admin

My manage.py runserver is successd.

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/
```

And It can enter the management interface.

But it throws an error when I run this code using another computer.

The error is :
http://paas-files.qiniudn.com/iRfEWVXNz1nSiztgfTBUOXNvqig2ycUiXFV03tHo.png

Is this what is wrong, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use same django version.
First you can see your django version on the good work computer. like this：

```
In [36]: import django

In [37]: django.VERSION
Out[37]: (1, 5, 5, 'final', 0)
```

From image we can find django version is 1.6.2
Maybe you can find where is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You have different versions of Django on this two computers. Try using [virtualenvs](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) and add requirements to your project